# How do I put data directly into clipboard ? (Ruby on Rails or JS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, clipboard

I'm working on a large RoR project, one aspect is going to be creating a chart in js, turning it into an image (gif or jpg) base64 encoding it, and then putting it into the clipboard for the user to paste into some other application.

I know about the clipboard gem and clipboard.js, but everything seems to only want text? do I have to base64 the image, and then assume that the paste recipient will do the correct thing with the base64 text? Do I not base64, and assume that the clipboard library can handle image data and text?

The documentation on these things seems minimal